# Incorporating prior knowledge to machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Say I have a data set of students with features such as income level, gender, parents' education levels, school, etc. And the target variable is say, passing or failing a national exam. We can train a machine learning model to predict, given these values whether a student is likely to pass or fail (say in sklearn, using predict_prob we can say the probability of passing)

Now say I have a different set of information which has nothing to do with the previous data set, which includes the schools and percentage of students from that particular school who has passed that national exam last year and years before. say, schoolA: 10%, schoolB: 15%, etc.

How can I use this additional knowledge to improve my model. For sure this data is valuable. (Students from certain schools have a higher chance of passing the exam due to their educational facilities, qualified staff, etc.).

Do i some how add this information as a new feature to the data set? If so what is the recommend way. Or do I use this information after the model prediction and somehow combine these to get a final probability ? Obviously an average or a weighted average doesn't work due to the second data set having probabilities in the range below 20% which then drags the total probability very low. How do data scientist usually incorporate this kind of prior knowledge? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try different ways to add this data and see if your model will be able to learn on this set. More likely you'll see right away, that this additional data will just confuse the model. Mostly because you're already providing more precise data on each student of the school and the model has more freedom to use this information.
But artificial neural network training is all about continuous trials and errors, so you definitely should try to train it with all possible data you can imagine to see if it'll be able to get a descent error in the end.

Comment: Thank You for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the average pass percentage of the students' school as a new feature of each student is worth to try.